# Keep Carriage Return / New Line while using STRING_ESCAPE in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following SQL Query that gives me some troubles with newline formatting when I am using the  STRING_ESCAPE function to json type

```
STRING_ESCAPE('Something', 'json')
```

the sql result ignores the carriage return/new line formatting:

```
Tænder, ingen side, Andre\r\nTænder, ingen side, Åbne sår
```

But when I am ignoring the STRING_ESCAPE funktion, it then shows the result as expected:

```
Tænder, ingen side, Andre
Tænder, ingen side, Åbne sår
```

Is it possible to apply the newline rule, while using this STRING_ESCAPE function ?.

```
         (
            SELECT
                STRING_ESCAPE(STRING_AGG(
                CASE WHEN iod.Status IN ('RejectedDiagnosisFirstDecision', 'RejectedDiagnosisReconsideration')
                    THEN
                        CONCAT_WS(', '
                            , iod.BodyPart
                            , iod.Side
                            , iod.InjuryType
                        )
                    ELSE NULL
            END, CONCAT(CHAR(13), CHAR(10))), 'json')
            FROM InjuryObjectDiagnosis
            INNER JOIN ParsedInjuryObjectDiagnosis iod ON InjuryObjectDiagnosis.Id = iod.Id
            WHERE iod.CaseId = acc.CaseId
        ) AS EndDiagnosisRejected
```

Comment: You'll have to replace them back in if you want them retain, and other values not. You can't choose what value (or aren't) escaped with [`STRING_ESCAPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: The JSON standard mandates that control characters *must* be escaped, and that includes CR/LF. Replacing them "back" afterwards is potentially problematic, if the input strings themselves contain (unescaped) `\r` (since this will end up as `\\r`, which should not be turned into `\<CR>`). You are better off leaving the output as-is, if it's supposed to be valid JSON.

Comment: that is how the JSON formatting rules work. You cannot bypass it. But you could use replace afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do the `string_escape` before the `string_agg` ?

```
   (
            SELECT
                STRING_AGG(
                STRING_ESCAPE(CASE WHEN iod.Status IN ('RejectedDiagnosisFirstDecision', 'RejectedDiagnosisReconsideration')
                    THEN
                        CONCAT_WS(', '
                            , iod.BodyPart
                            , iod.Side
                            , iod.InjuryType
                        )
                    ELSE NULL
            END, 'json'), CONCAT(CHAR(13), CHAR(10)))
            FROM InjuryObjectDiagnosis
            INNER JOIN ParsedInjuryObjectDiagnosis iod ON InjuryObjectDiagnosis.Id = iod.Id
            WHERE iod.CaseId = acc.CaseId
        ) AS EndDiagnosisRejected
```

I think that should solve your problem.